# How to get the URL of the response? in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

in the post I send the bytes

```
Future<dynamic> postHttpFile(String table,dynamic image,String userToken) async {
  String url = env.URL + table;
  final urlFinal = Uri.parse(url);
Map<String, String> headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + userToken
  };

  var request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", urlFinal);

  var multipartFileSign = http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('upload', image,);

  request.files.add(multipartFileSign);

  request.headers.addAll(headers);
  var response = await request.send();
  //var responseData = await response.stream.bytesToString();
  var res = await http.Response.fromStream(response);
  inspect(res);
  return res;
  
}
```

in the inspect I receive this...

bodyBytes:NativeUint8List ([123, 34, 102, 105, 108, 101, 115, 34, 58, 91, 93, 125])
contentLength:12
headers:Map (2 items)
isRedirect:false
persistentConnection:true
reasonPhrase:"OK"
request:MultipartRequest (POST https://**********/contacts/uploadAvatar)
statusCode:200

in return i get this..

Instance of 'Response'

I need the URL

Comment: Perhaps you want `res.body`

Answer (score 0):

You should try this.

```
  var multipartFileSign = http.MultipartFile.fromPath('upload', image.path,);
```